# Multi threading using POSIX Semaphore in c

Tags: c, multithreading, semaphore

I am trying to use semaphores to capture frames from the video camera and do object recognition in parallel , I have a doubt here:

**main.c**(**with edits**)

```
sem_t sem_1;
sem_init(&sem_1, 0, 1);  //Initial value of 1
sem_init(&sem_2, 0, 1);  //Initial value of 1

int val_sem1,val_sem2;
sem_getvalue(&mutex_ping1, &val_sem1);
printf("%d %d \r\n", val_sem1,val_sem2);   //Output = 1 1(Correct)

//Create thread
trc = pthread_create(&tid_1, NULL, objrecognition_2, &obj_num[0]);
trc = pthread_create(&tid_2, NULL, objrecognition_3, &obj_num[1]);

Sleep(5000);


 sem_getvalue(&sem_1, &val_sem1);
 sem_getvalue(&sem_2, &val_sem2);
 printf("%d %d \r\n", val_sem1,val_sem2);  //Ideal output? 

 //Few line of code

while(1)
{
   //Get camera frame from video camera
   ....
   ....

   frame[index%3] = currentframe; //Using 3 backup buffers to avoid race around


   //For the very first time always sem_post(logic to keep index > index_use)
   if ((check))   //Initial value of check =1
  {
      check = 0;//Check is made 0 here after permanently
      sem_post(&sem1);
      sem_post(&sem2);
  }


   sem_getvalue(&sem_1, &val_sem1);//Get the present semaphore1 value
   sem_getvalue(&sem_2, &val_sem2);//Get the present semaphore2 value


   //This part of the code is activated from the second run because of check variable

   //Check if thread has completed one loop run and is waiting on sem_wait()
   if ((val_sem_1 == 0) &&  (val_sem_2 == 0) && (check==0)) //Checking if thread has completed one loop run
   {
     index_use++;    //The thread uses frame[index_use % 3] to process 
                    //so that it does not collide with frame[index % 3]
     sem_post(&sem_1);
     sem_post(&sem_2);
   }

   index++;
}
```

Output should be 0 since sem_wait in thread(in **functions.c** below) must have decremented the value to 0 and should have got blocked

But I am getting random outputs such as 1, -1 and sometimes 0.

Could anyone please help me out here, Is my understanding of semaphores wrong??

**functions.c**

```
void*  objrecognition_2(void* arg2)
{
   while (1)
  {

    sem_wait(&mutex_ping2);

   ...
   ...
  }
}
```

**edits**

I have put a break point before calling sem_post() and also keeping a 5 second delay after creating the thread.

Hence the thread gets created and has to decrement semaphore by 1 and become zero and should wait untill sem_post() gets activated.

Now it prints only -1 at the second printf.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_getvalue.3.html):

> If one or more processes or threads are blocked waiting to lock the
>   semaphore with sem_wait(3), POSIX.1 permits two possibilities for the
>   value returned in sval: either 0 is returned; **or a negative number
>   whose absolute value is the count of the number of processes and
>   threads currently blocked** in sem_wait(3).  Linux adopts the former
>   behavior.

So the value isn't random, it has meaning. In your particular sample code:

- -1 means `objrecognition_2` calls `sem_wait` again without calling `sem_post` before. So it's in a deadlock.
- 0 means `objrecognition_2` hasn't deadlocked itself yet.
- 1 means `objrecognition_2` didn't call `sem_wait` on the semaphore at all yet.

---

Following your edits and discussion in the comments to my answer, it's clear to me you are trying to implement a thread barrier by yourself. I suggest you just use the [pthread barrier implementation instead](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_barrier_wait.html).

Comment: Why would sem_wait be called again , since initial semaphore value is 1, so sem_wait must decrement the semaphore value to 0 and go to wait mode till sem_post increments the semaphore value.

Comment: @NithinGA - In the code you posted you `sem_wait` at the start of a loop. And you don't show yourself calling `sem_post`. So in the next iteration, `sem_wait` will see that the semaphore is 0 and wait. The thread is deadlocked with itself.

Comment: Actually I have put a break point before calling sem post(Please check the edits)...Now in the thread the first statement is sem_wait...So if I allow 5 seconds after creating the thread and then print the value of semaphore value, It has to get blocked at sem_wait right??

Comment: @NithinGA - Your edit doesn't have any call to `sem_post` in sight. Your code sample still has the same symptoms I described. If you want to discuss something about `sem_post`, then please post code that calls it.

Comment: @StorTeller, I have edited the question , does it give some clarity as to what I am doing

Comment: @NithinGA - The call to sleep seems to me like the cause of your deadlock. While the main thread sleeps, the spawned one calls `sem_wait` twice and goes into a deadlock. Then it's never true that `val_sem1 == 0` and you don't call `sem_post`. You seem to want only simple mutual exclusion, why not use a `pthread_mutex_t`?

Comment: Will try mutex, I have edited more ,please see again, if I was in the middle of typing new edits,  If I remove Sleep, would that help, basically I need to make sure that when the while loop starts, the semaphore value must be 0 and then it has to alternate between 1 and 0 using sem_post and sem_wait combination

Comment: @NithinGA - I'm not certain if the actual value of the semaphore is important to your application or not, in so much as the exclusion. Give `pthread_mutex_t` a try instead if it isn't. And I suggest you post another question about the use of the semaphore if a mutex isn't working for you.

Comment: The actual value of the thread is important because I have multiple threads which I have not shown, so all the threads must access the same frame at the same time and sem_post is activated if all the threads are in the wait mode ,hence check the semaphore values before sem_post

Comment: @NithinGA - You want the threads to wait at a certain point until they all reached it? And only then continue execution? Possibly multiple times?

Comment: Exactly that is what I want it to do, I have added edits for two threads, please have a look

Comment: @NithinGA - Then what you want is a thread barrier (see [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_barrier_wait.html)). I now see that you attempt to implement it yourself (which is a nice exercise, but I think your life will be made easier by just using the pthread implementation).

Comment: Thanks, will try it out

Answer (score 0):

You are getting random value as their is a timing issue here. To make sure the thread already started and decremented the semaphore I suggest you to wait for 1 second  see the code below:

```
//After say 20 lines of code, such that the thread actually gets created

// put the main thread to sleep for 1 second as 
// 20 lines of code may not be too much to give 
// the opportunity to another thread to work and capture the semaphore.

sem_getvalue(&mutex_ping1, &val_sem1);
```

Comment: Good Idea, I tried it, gave a 5 second delay to be safe, Now it is always -1, so as @StoryTeller pointed out it may be calling sem_wait() again and decrementing twice and hence -1 always...But why is this happening I do not understand